# Hibernate unidirectional ManyToMany delete only from association table

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

I am fairly new to java and hibernate (with annotation) and not sure if the below is correct.  I have a unidirectional many to many relationship between two tables as in the example below:

```
class Group { 
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
            @JoinTable(
                    name = "Group_Students",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName="group_id),
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName="student_id)
            )
         private Set<Student> students;
}
```

The following works ok:
-   insert in table Student if I save an instance of Group -> this works ok
-   update in table Student if a student instance of the Group is modified -> this works ok
I want to delete the record from the Group and association table but keep the ones in the Student table. Currently before deleting the Group record, I set the instance’s student set to null (`students = null`). This seems to work perfectly, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it or if it is a bad practice – it seems that this solution is only a workaround and might cause issues in future. Do you have any other suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad practice. You should almost never cascade `ALL` or `REMOVE` in a many-to-many association, because after deleting a `Group`, you probably don't want the deletion to be cascaded to all the students belonging to that group.

The correct approach is to specify only the desired cascade types (without the two mentioned above). Then, since the association is unidirectional, you can simply remove the `Group` (without any changes to the `students` collection).

Comment: So by changing the cascade type, it is possible that when adding a new Student it will be inserted / updated in the table and on removing it will only remove the link in the association table and not in the Student table?  - Currently deletion is not cascading to students due to the students = null statement

Comment: I will try that. Thank you